# POST form values to C# WebMethod via ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

I'm trying to serialize some form values into a json object using [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and then POST the form values to a `WebMethod` in a service.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var foobar = $(this).closest('#add-question').serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Services/QuestionsService.asmx/SubmitQuestion",
                data: "{foo:[" + JSON.stringify(foobar) + "]}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#btn").text(data.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class QuestionsService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string SubmitQuestion(string foo)
    {
        //do something with foo

        return "Message Sent";
    }
}
```

However I kept getting a 500 error on the service:

> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/SubmitQuestion'.

I found a similar question which recommended adding:

```
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```

To the web.config, this seemed to solve the first issue. But I now get an error in the service complaining that the form parameter `foo` is missing yet it has clearly been supplied:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: foo.
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Is there something I'm missing?

I think it might be an issue with `serializeArray()` as it hits the web method fine if I pass in a simple json object such as:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
```

Am I using `serializeArray()` incorrectly?

Here is the output of `data` after being stringified:

```
{
foo: [
    [
        {
            "name": "__EVENTTARGET",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "__EVENTARGUMENT",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "__VIEWSTATE",
            "value": "RHqOeKRh4e+2IZH9ZdPatwEklxypUzemNeDv7sO4l8vIR2TrECRFZvalrpbvVre0e6gkY9ZG3618dtU3BhYFW3YNn2y6VqeZlL5hmG/WPLTtZN8lhDkEl1bGOGWBsY52zVxWECkAC2hGtHwF5plmKsL3sHp3nFxh3yzWoGP1LwAc4sAZ/rgKvozqCp/4FfB6P4jBUQnL7Q5EkNsjWBntsXbUswC3cJpS22vgoJFHDh8Lm9n/VGzC86FUWipvGmOJ9/KVSlUBbJE3J0Fs6UZi+E6T1Ql+I8XBZlZOzDlbq40="
        },
        {
            "name": "ctl00$MainContent$txtName",
            "value": "name field"
        },
        {
            "name": "ctl00$MainContent$txtEmailAddress",
            "value": "email address field"
        },
        {
            "name": "ctl00$MainContent$txtLocation",
            "value": "location field"
        },
        {
            "name": "ctl00$MainContent$chkAnonymous",
            "value": "on"
        },
        {
            "name": "ctl00$MainContent$txtQuestion",
            "value": "question field"
        },
        {
            "name": "__EVENTVALIDATION",
            "value": "ileV4/vPquayqiSQJEAvq1oHpIAkHN+fy4QhqOrQpp7NxE4z15rvbTH6BfaSCFFwt96JAp1aqQzuOFCTzc6KSEE6iWDmSDRcJWWOzyksSoXpAMBwLk3F6oAaWa4EIjEUb+2b/PJobySl5BaU3TG0JCZyHK2fxj5HXd8DG89gnmVXemTwq1Ax4BgJw1Z5z1uT8Sw7Xk6inUHAZ0NJH4QdTQ=="
        }
    ]
]
```

}

Comment: `$('#add-question').serializeArray()` what is the output of it?

Comment: You should `.serializeArray()` your form. is this `$('#add-question')` your form's id?

Comment: @Jai, yes that's my form. I'll add the output as an image to the question rather than paste it here.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify(data)` - just post `data: data`

Comment: @Archer That was the first thing I tried

Comment: Keep it like that then, as it is "stringyfied" by the ajax call, so you were originally stringyfying it twice (what a strange word to keep typing :p)  At least that will be ruled out :)

Comment: Do you think using `serialize()` instead would be a better idea? It converts the data to a URL query string key/value collection and then doing `data: 'foo=' + data,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this. I needed to make the parameter in the `WebMethod` an `object` rather than a `string`:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SubmitQuestion(object foo)
{
    //do something with foo

    return "Message Sent";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to send data as

```
data: {'foo': JSON.stringify(foobar)},
```

or

```
data: {foo: JSON.stringify(foobar)},
```

the data would be sent as json and the value stored is a string which will be passed to your webmethod's string parameter

Comment: Did you give it a try after you got the second error message (System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: foo. at...) also?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you had this answered but I believe you also need the signature of the method to have static in it for the web method to run correctly.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SubmitQuestion(string foo)
{
    //do something with foo

    return "Message Sent";
}
```